# Existence of primitive roots

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Fix $p$ prime . Exist $q$ prime that p is primitive root $Z/qZ$ ?
I think that this is true (numerical evidence).

Comment: I don't think it would hurt to be a little more explicit in what you mean by "numerical evidence".

Comment: This [has already been proven](http://wstein.org/edu/2007/spring/ent/ent-html/node29.html).

Comment: @NobleMushtak The link only shows that there exists some primitive root modulo $q$, but not necessarily that the given $p$ is a primitive root.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh...OK. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The link provided is to a different question. I don't know the answer to the current one. It is a consequence of a result of Heath-Brown that there are at most two primes for which the proposed conjecture fails.

Answer (score 1):

We need to put some conditions on $q$, such as $p\lt q$. This is because, for example, any odd prime $p$ is technically a primitive root of $2$.

The question, revised to include the condition $q\gt p$, is closely related to [Artin's Conjecture.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots#cite_note-4) It is a consequence of a result of Heath-Brown that there are at most two primes $p$ for which there is no prime $q\gt p$ such that $p$ is a primitive root of $q$.

*Added:* The Heath-Brown paper does not seem to be available online. [Murty](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~agboola/teaching/2005/winter/old-115A/murty.pdf) has a good survey article.